# MongoDB Driver + Express.js Простая регистрация MongoError: E11000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Здравствуйте.

Была простая регистрация на MongoDB Driver забита коллбеками, решил переписати с помощью asyc/await.
Но появилась ошибка. С чем связана, не пойму. Может кто объяснить? Спасибо)

> MongoError:
>
> index: name_1 dup key: { : null }E11000 duplicate key error collection: FirstApp.users

Код:

```
const config = require ('../config');
const mongodb = require ('mongodb');
const ObjectId = require('objectid');
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const DBurl = config.DBurl;

const SaveUser = async function (UserEmail, UserPassword, sessionID) {

    const User = {
        //_id: new ObjectId(),
        "UserEmail": UserEmail,
        "UserPassword": UserPassword,
        "SessionID": sessionID,
    };

    console.log(User);

    try {
        const db = await MongoClient.connect(DBurl);

        const collection = db.collection('users');

        //collection.createIndex({"name" : 1}, {"unique" : true});
        const result = await collection.insertOne(User);

        if (result.acknowledged)
            return {save: true};

        else
            return {save: false};

    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
};

const Register = router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const UserEmail = req.body.UserEmail;
    const UserPassword = req.body.RegisterPassword;
    const UserConfirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
    const sessionID = req.sessionID;

    if (UserPassword === UserConfirmPassword) {

        const result = await SaveUser(UserEmail, UserPassword, sessionID);

        result.save ?
            res.status(200)
                .json({isBusy: false}) :
            res.status(500)
                .json({error: result, isBusy: true});
    }

    else if(UserEmail || UserPassword || UserConfirmPassword === undefined)
        res.status(400)
            .send('Bad request');

    else if (UserConfirmPassword !== UserPassword)
    res.status(400)
            .send('Wrong confirm password');
});
module.exports = Register;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я туплю)

У меня в базе нету поля `name` :) Но база была забита левыми индексами.

Решил это так:

Очистил все индексы в базе

```
dropIndexes()
```

У меня должен быть один уникальный `UserEmail`

```
createIndex({"UserEmail": 1}, {"unique": true});
```

Вообщем это все)